# How to convert a list of tbl_regression objects to a single tbl_regression object?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to add significance stars to a `gtsummary` table that combines multiple models, but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to resolve.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Create a list of tbl_regression objects
models <-  c("disp", "disp + hp") %>% 
  map(
    ~ paste("vs", .x, sep = " ~ ") %>% 
      as.formula() %>% 
      glm(data = mtcars,
          family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>% 
      tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE))

# Try to add significance stars
models %>% 
  add_significance_stars(
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}",
    thresholds = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05),
    hide_ci = TRUE,
    hide_p = TRUE,
    hide_se = FALSE
  ) 
#> Error: Error in argument 'x='. Expecting object of class 'tbl_regression', or 'tbl_uvregression'
```

It seems that the list `models` is not an object of class `tbl_regression`, and therefore cannot be passed to `add_significance_stars()`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `models` object is a list of `gtsummary` tables. Hence, as you did when you created the tables you have to use `map` to loop over the `list` to add significance stars to each table:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

models %>%
  map(
    ~ add_significance_stars(.x,
      pattern = "{estimate}{stars}",
      thresholds = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05),
      hide_ci = TRUE,
      hide_p = TRUE,
      hide_se = FALSE
    )
  )
```

Comment: You could also pass this list of gtsummary tables to `tbl_stack()` to put everything into a single table.

Answer (score 2):

As you indicate, `models` is a list of objects of class `tbl_regression`. You can just use `lapply`, like this:

```
models = lapply(models,
  add_significance_stars,
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}",
    thresholds = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05),
    hide_ci = TRUE,
    hide_p = TRUE,
    hide_se = FALSE
  )
```

Or you could include the call to `add_significance_stars()` in the original `map()`